# slideToggle menu to hide

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I've used the following

```
$("#button").on("click",function(e){
    $("#nav").slideToggle();
});
```

to have a nav that slides down for when my page is viewed in a mobile setting. The #nav has display:none in the CSS and so it makes since that it has `display:block` for when I click the `#button`.

However, if I don't "close" the nav first (or reclick `#button`) and I resize the window, the `#nav` will remain `display:block` and appear past 479px. I've tried something along the lines of

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   if( $(window).innerWidth()>459 && $("#nav").css("display")!=none ) $("#nav").hide();
});
```

and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post relevant HTML.

Comment: You probably need quotes on "none", but I'd use .is(":visible") anyway.

Comment: What is it in my solution that stops you from implementing?

Comment: You script is incorrect. You are not using the if statement properly.

Comment: the quotes around "none" seemed to fix it -- thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Feel free to accept and/or upvote my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `max-width` (or regular `width`) to `#nav` in the CSS. That will kick into effect when the div is shown.

edit: this is only if you still want the div to show up, just not expand the full width. If you want it to disappear when the window is wider than 459, see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav{
    width:100%;
    padding:30px;
    background:#1d1d1d;
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

Based on the size of the window, we will display the `DIV` below:

```
$(window).resize(setDivVisibility);
function setDivVisibility(){
     if (($(window).width()) < '750'){  //change pixels to match your needs
     $('#nav').css('display','block');  
     } else {  
     $('#nav').css('display','none');  
     } 
 }
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/8m5By/ (try resizing and the div will appear)